# Module dependencies in lib/

Tags: module, magento-1, dependency

In order to ease future Magento upgrades, I am working to extract custom modules and put each in the its own tidy git repository.

However, many of these modules depend on Magento-agnostic code that lives in `lib/`. Since multiple modules depend on it, I can't very well hack together a `composer.json` and put the dependency in `app/code/*/NameSpace/Module/vendor/`.

Currently, my plan is to deploy the code using modman, but I could set up a firegento-style composer repository if that gives more flexibility.

What processes do you recommend for quick, reliable deployments? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like `composer/installers` includes the `magento-library` type!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using Composer with the [PSR-0 autoloader](http://github.com/magento-hackathon/Magento-PSR-0-Autoloader) project lately. Works well for modern dependencies.

Comment: This looks promising. I'll try it out and accept if it does the trick.

Comment: Iam also working on a more pure composer version of magento which you can find here https://github.com/WizardsFugue/WizardsFugue_Magento_Example